# Intersect data frame columns where values don't match exactly in R

Tags: r

I have two different data frames comparing gene expression from two different experiments (lets call them df1 and df2). In both data frames, the first column is a factor variable that lists the genes of interest (df1$gene, df2$gene). I want to find where these columns intersect. Normally I would just create a character vector using something like

`common<-Reduce(intersect, list(df1$gene,df2$gene))`

My problem is that the formatting isn't the same regarding how the genes were identified in this case (since they came from different people). For example, df1$genes uses conventional abbreviations alone (as it should be for easy data analysis), while df2$genes includes a description with the abbreviation included somewhere in parentheses. The descriptions also sometimes contain parentheses independent of the abbreviation, and sometimes just use the abbreviation without any description or parentheses. Below I've included a mock print of what three rows would look like from each data set. note that these are the same three genes (in different order) for each df.

```
head (df1$genes, n=3)
[1] TFPI2    SLC26A9    IL6  

head (df2$genes, n=3)
[1] solute carrier family 26, member 9 (SLC26A9)     interleukin 6 (interferon, beta 2) (IL6),     TFPI2
```

What I want is just an output of where these lists intersect, in the format of df1 labelling (i.e. just abbreviations). I am very new to using R, and can't figure out how to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You might start by tinkering with the `str_extract` function in the `stringr` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html. If you can get code that extracts just the part you want from `df2`, then you can use the `match` function to look for matches.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how messy your full dataset is, you might be able to match a lot of these with `agrep`, e.g.:

```
genes1 <- c("TFPI2", "SLC26A9", "IL6", "TP53")
genes2 <- c("solute carrier family 26, member 9 (SLC26A9)",
  "interleukin 6 (interferon, beta 2) (IL6)",
  "TFPI2")

# fuzzy string matching
matches <- sapply(genes1, agrep, genes2)

# find 0 length matches (misses), 
# could also handle >1 matches here
matches[sapply(matches, length) == 0] <- NA

data.frame(
  symbol = genes1,
  match = genes2[unlist(matches)]
)
#    symbol                                        match
# 1   TFPI2                                        TFPI2
# 2 SLC26A9 solute carrier family 26, member 9 (SLC26A9)
# 3     IL6     interleukin 6 (interferon, beta 2) (IL6)
# 4    TP53                                         <NA>
```

Comment: can it be expanded to more than two columns where this is what I would like to do..I have made a question.